# Interact.jl unable to create widget in Jupyter notebook + Julia

Tags: jupyter-notebook, julia

I have recently installed Julia and trying to run Interact but it seems that Interact is not able to generate widgets.

I did the following steps:

- Install Julia
- Add IJulia package
- Add Interact package
- Add WebIO package
- Run WebIO.install_jupyter_nbextension()
- Run a Jupyter notebook.

The following screenshot shows the error I get - truncated for brevity

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For someone else facing this issue, I did a complete uninstall (complete wipe-out) and install and it worked.

For anaconda, I uninstalled it by removing all configuration files etc. I followed Option B in the link below:
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

For Julia:

- I deleted the installation
- Deleted the .julia folder in C:\Users<username>.julia
- Deleted registry associated with Julia
- Deleted Julia folder in C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia 1.5.2